# Command Line Input Working Incorrectly

Tags: c

Okay so I made this program to help me out with my homework and because I wanted to improve my C expertise. Everything compiles fine when I do "gcc file.c -lm", but when I run it with a number at the command line as an argument, my program only returns 70.0000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


double temp(double hour){
    double t = (3.14/12)*hour;
    double c = cos((double)t);
    double temp = 13 * c + 57;
    return temp; 
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[]){
    double temperature = temp((double)atol(argv[0]));

    printf("%f\n", temperature);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`argv[0]` is probably your program name.  You want `argv[1]`, I expect.  Check out [this tutorial](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) for a quick and easy explanation.

Besides that, is there a reason you're using `atol(3)` and casting to `double` rather than just using [`atof(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atof) which returns a `double` directly?

Comment: Do you know why the program name is always the first variable in the array? Thanks for the tutorial too!

Comment: I can't comment on historical reasons, but it's sure helpful for a program like busybox that does different things based on the name you use to invoke it.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, that `argv` is the arguments used to launch the program, which looks something like this:

```
/path/to/my/exec value
```

So, when you access the first element of that array, `argv[0]`, you are accessing the following:

```
/path/to/my/exec
```

What you really need is the second element of the array, `argv[1]`, which should contain this:

```
value
```